# Initialising map with an existing map in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, maps

I start with one map `myInitialMap`. i would like to create another map `myNewMap` that is initialised with `myInitialMap`.

```
val myInitialMap = mapOf<String, Int>("one" to 1, "two" to 2)
val myNewMap = mapOf(myInitialMap)
```

I get error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Pair<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>
Found: Map<String, Int>
```

How can I initialise `myNewMap` with `myInitialMap`?

Comment: What is your use case? You can use `myInitialMap.toMap()` to create a copy. However, in your example both maps are read only, so you could just do `val myNewMap = myInitialMap`.

Comment: I am not trying to create a copy but rather **initialise** a map with a pre-existing map. The background is i am using state

Comment: If your code worked (`mapOf(myInitialMap)`), it would be equivalent to `myInitialMap.toMap()`. Initializing a map with values from another map is equivalent to creating a copy. If you have a different issue please post that.

Comment: @gpunto I am not trying to create a copy but rather **initialise** a map with a pre-existing map. `myInitialMap` is in my viewModel and `myNewMap` is in a state holder class (as per jetpack compose architecture). So when my state holder is initialised, i need the `myNewMap` to be initialised with the existing data in the viewModel (represented by `myInitialMap`).

Comment: What do you think is the difference between creating a copy and initializing a new map with the values of the existing one?

Comment: @gpunto This still would not work in my use case. e.g. `var copyMap = viewModel.portfolioData.value!!.toMap()` and then `var viewModelMap = mutableStateMapOf<String,PortfolioDataModel>(copyMap)`. This still gives the same error.

Comment: So your question is not about initializing a random map, it's about creating a Jetpack Compose mutable state map. To do that you can do: `mutableStateMapOf<String, Int>().apply { putAll(myInitialMap) }`

Comment: Thank you, this is it. It is unfortunate that it cannot be initialised directly within the the `()` but instead requires an apply block to be appended. Appreciated.

Comment: Remember you can just create your own `mutableStateMapOf` function that does what you wish.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `myInitialMap.toList().toMutableStateMap()`.

The `...Of()` functions in Kotlin all follow the convention of taking individual entries as varargs, which is why `mapOf(myInitialMap)` doesn't, and shouldn't, work. Since these functions use the arguments to determine the generic types, the list/set versions could not possibly support also having overloads that accept an Iterable parameter with all the entries to include, because you might actually want a list of Iterables (2D collection). For consistency, `mapOf` must behave the same.

Function naming/behavior conventions:

- `...Of()`: A function taking a vararg parameter of all the individual values to put in the collection. The argument type can be used for the compiler to infer the generic type(s) of the collection.
- `.to...Map/Set/List()`: An extension function that creates a shallow copy or new type of collection from the entries of the collection it is called on.
- `.as...()`: An extension function that wraps the original object in another one. For example, `asIterable()` or `asSequence()` will return those types, but they will read from the original object. They are not copies.